# Ignoring all the non float value when convert string to float to sum them

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import-csv

I'm trying to convert all string values to floating values to make an addition but, there are strings present in my csv, and it returns this error:

```
L.append([i, j, sum(i for i in map(float, filter(None, 
k)) if i in {0.5, 1, 2})])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'l0g0dim'
```

How can i ignore  strings with letters, comma, and other non-convertible characters and sum them with out problem ?

**Sample file3.csv**

```
1754|2014-06-13 07:00:00|0|0.5|0
1754|2014-06-13 08:00:00|0|2|0.5
1754|2014-06-13 09:00:00|0|a0|b0|2
1278|2014-01-26 18:00:00|light subcoatal draft ...|0|0|2|0.5
1754|2014-06-04 19:00:00|0|leg dim|0|0
1754|2014-06-13 10:00:00|0|(C) fins|0|0
```

**Code**

```
    import csv
    import re
    import time
    from io import StringIO

replacements = (
("(B)", "0"), ("(D)", "1"), ("Entrée air absente", "2"),

("+", "0.5"), ("++", "1"), ("+++", "2"),

("(S) +", "0.5"), ("(S) expi. ++", "1"), ("(S) +++", "2"),

("100", "0"), ("99", "0"), ("98", "0"), ("97", "0"), ("96", "0"),
("95", "0"), ("94", "1"), ("93", "1"),
("92", "1"), ("91", "1"), ("90", "1"), ("89", "1"),
("Bruits de transmission", "0"), ("Fatigué/épuisé", "0"), (" *", "0"), ("tirage sous costal", "0"), ("léger BAN", "0"),   )

replvalues = dict(replacements)
regex = "|".join(map(re.escape,                                 
replvalues.keys()))
repl = lambda x: replvalues.get(x.string[x.start():x.end()])

with open("file3.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f_in, \
    open("file4.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f_out:


    for i in f_in:
        line = re.sub(regex, repl, i)
        f_out.write(line)

with open("file4.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f_in, \
     open("file5.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
L = []
with f_in as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='|')
    for i, j, *k in reader:
      L.append([i, j, sum(i for i in map(float, filter(None, k)) if i in {0.5, 1, 2})])
    f_out.write(L)
print(L)
```

Comment: So for this line: `1754|2014-06-13 07:00:00|0|0.5|0`, you would want to add `0`, `0.5` and `0`? What is your expected output?

Comment: I would suggest using `pandas.read_csv`, then coerce the columns of the resulting dataframe to `float`

Comment: For the first line there is no problem, but for the third ilne i would like :  `1754|2014-06-13 09:00:00|0|0|0|2` and for the next line `1278|2014-01-26 18:00:00|0|0|2|0.5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why filter twice?

```
filter(None, k)           # filter
(... if i in {0.5, 1, 2}) # another filter
```

You can filter once and simply remove non-float values by checking a set of strings for the appropriate values (values **expected** in your CSV):

```
L.append([i, j, sum(float(i) for x in k if x in {'0.5', '1', '2'})])
                                       #|<-      filter       ->|
```

Incompatible string values such as the string `'leg dim'` never get past the filter and therefore do not make it to the final `float` call.

Comment: @jpp I don't understand.

Comment: I see what you're doing now. The main point is filter for strings not floats. Let's just hope they don't have `0.50` or `1.0`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

put this part

```
for i, j, *k in reader:
    L.append([i, j, sum(i for i in map(float, filter(None, k)) if i in {0.5, 1, 2})])
f_out.write(L)
```

into an `try....except`-block with checking if the desired value is a float. if yes, append, if no, continue with the next value.